# Is Mutual Information(MI) an important factor to consider in unsupervised learning (Clustering)?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mutual-information

I have a supervised learning problem. The final step in the solving process is segmentation. Do features with the lowest MI affect the clustering process?

My problem about Churn Customers Segmentation: I found out some features with no MI at all. Do I drop these features?

Comment: Please note that while SO is suitable for ML questions, these should be related to their programmatic aspect. [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/)

Comment: Is your problem supervised or unsupervised? Title and question body describe different things.

Comment: Note that lower MI is not an indicator that there's no relationship between variables. Two variables may have different rules relating them for different values of a third variable. If your data is not stratified for this third variable, this rules can shadow each other (therefore you get a low MI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a feature important experiment, like this.

https://github.com/ash-wicus-ml/Notebooks/blob/master/XG%20Boost%20-%20Feature%20Importance.ipynb

When you know what your X-variable is, you can run some clustering exercises.

https://github.com/ash-wicus-ml/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20Algorithms%20Compared.ipynb